# Postgresql Patroni documentation on installation/troubleshooting

Tags: postgresql, patroni

Anyone aware where I can find further documentation on Patroni?

https://github.com/zalando/patroni

I've looked into the github docs, but it doesn't contain much documentation on usage/problems found during installation/etc. It seems the examples focus on etcd only.

Comment: We recently updated the [Patroni docs](https://github.com/zalando/patroni). Please let us know if anything is unclear by submitting an issue on the repo. -- Lauri at Zalando

Comment: Two years later and I feel your pain. I'm going through this process now of setting up, tearing down and re-setting up a patroni cluster to take over my existing streaming replication cluster. The documentation has a *LOT* of gaps and the Slack channel is hit-or-miss if someone is around that is willing to help.

I'm taking notes and will be submitting some documentation patches when all is said and done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately we don't have good documentation so far. Current README file doesn't cover even 50% of Patroni functionality, but I can tell for sure that sample configuration files (postgres{0-2}).yml could be used as a good start.
There is no big difference between Etcd, ZooKeeper or Consul from user perspective. If you want to use ZooKeeper or Consul instead of Etcd, just comment/uncomment corresponding sections in the configuration files.

Currently the only big problem with the latest release of Patroni - it's not possible to change without restart any of the postgres parameters which were set from Patroni config file, but it's already fixed in the master branch. At the moment I'm working on possibility to change Patroni and postgres configuration dynamically. Basic idea is: configuration is stored in a configuration store (Etcd/ZooKeeper/Consul) and as soon as somebody changes it there it would be applied on the next iteration of HA loop.

If you have some concrete problems or questions don't hesitate to open an issue on the Patroni github page.

Comment: Can we install Patroni with Postgres1 Replica on the same server?

Answer (score 0):

You can find a details installation steps for [how to setup highly available postgresql cluster using Patroni and HAProxy](https://www.askvikram.com/how-to-set-up-a-highly-available-postgresql-cluster-using-patroni-and-haproxy)

Fully tested guide and working fine.